# How do I create a context menu for the tab header of a TabControlAdv

Tags: .net, syncfusion

I'd like to have a context menu for my tab headers in a Syncfusion TabControlAdv control, and have a separate menu for the controls inside each tab. The likely menu entries will be "Add Tab", "Delete Tab" and "Clone Tab", and neither of them makes much sense to show when the user rightclicks in the middle of my control (which will have a data grid). Can someone share a link or code snippet showing how I can do this?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried posting your question on the [Syncfusion Forums](http://www.syncfusion.com/support/forums)?